# How to ignore dependencies in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying React Native Windows for the first time now. Since I need to add the Windows platform to an existing app, there are already numerous dependencies. However some of them are not implemented for React Native Windows (or probably never will be). What I thought is that the bundler will now just ignore these dependencies. But I am wrong - it throws an error that the selected dependency is not available for this platform. So is there any possiblity to ignore specific dependencies for a specific platform?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, how I miss those days when I was all convinced React Native and thought it was a solution for everything.

The answer to my question is: No, there is no functionality for this unless you create your own packager.